# How to add column n from all csv files and store in another csv file (with the header being the filename from which the column came from)?

Tags: csv, awk, header

I have multiple .csv files and I want to extract a particular column from each. Lets say column 5. I want to take that column and add it to a csv file and append a new column onto it from each successive file. I am able to do this with the following code taken from someone else:

```
awk '{_[FNR]=(_[FNR] OFS $1)}END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) {sub(/^ /,"",_[i]); print _[i]}}' input*.csv > output.csv`
```

When I look at the output file I notice that the order in which the columns is added isn't sequential. As a result I was hoping to modify the code so that the header of the column is the filename from which the column came. How can I go about doing this?

For example:
input1.csv can be:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

input2.csv could be:

```
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
```

And I would want the output.csv to be:

```
input1.csv, input2.csv
5,15
10,20
```

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for sharing your efforts. Could you please post sample of input and expected output in your question too for better understanding of it.

Comment: I've edited the question - thanks!

Comment: Don't name a variable `_` - that's even worse for code readability than using a singe letter.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton - as I mentioned I got this code from someone else and have limited knowledge on awk. So I'm not 100% sure what the variable _ is? I know you shouldn't blindly use code and I'll make more of an effort to understand what is actually going on. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: You're welcome. `_[FNR]` is an array named `_` indexed by the value of the variable `FNR`. Almost anything else would have been a better name - even `a[]` would be better than `_[]` because at least then you know at a glance that it is simply an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1{
  fileName=(fileName?fileName", ":"")FILENAME
}
{
  max=(max>FNR?max:FNR)
  val[FNR]=(val[FNR] == "" ? "" : val[FNR] OFS) $NF
}
END{
  print fileName
  for(i=1;i<=max;i++){
    print val[i]
  }
}
' *.csv  > output.csv
```

With shown samples output file named `output.csv` will be crated with following contents.

```
input1.csv, input2.csv
5,15
10,20
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                           ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }                             ##Starting BEGIN section from here and setting field separator and output field separator as comma here.
FNR==1{                                         ##If this is first line of all Input_file
  fileName=(fileName?fileName", ":"")FILENAME   ##Creating fileName which has current Input_file name in it and keep adding it.
}
{
  max=(max>FNR?max:FNR)                         ##Creating max, to get highest number of lines.
  val[FNR]=(val[FNR] == "" ? "" : val[FNR] OFS) $NF        ##Creating val with index of FNR and keep adding values of last field in it.
}
END{                                            ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print fileName                                ##Printing all file names in outputFile.
  for(i=1;i<=max;i++){                          ##Starting for loop from 1 to max here.
    print val[i]                                ##Printing array val value here.
  }
}
' *.csv > output.csv                            ##Mentioning all *.csv files here.
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13 I've just tried it, but it didn't print just one column from each file. It printed everything from every file. It has printed the header with the files separated like by a space "filename1, ,filename2, , filename3......".

Comment: @BenWest, could you please try my edited solution? just refresh this page once and run latest solution, let me know how it goes, it worked fine for me, let me know.

Comment: Perfect, my fault, I realised that my csv files didn't actually have the right delimiter. If I wanted to change which column needs printing, how would I go about it? Say I wanted to print column 3 of the input files rather than 5?

Comment: @BenWest, your welcome. In case of changing column number change from `$NF` to `$3` (where $NF is last field of the line), cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Nevermind - I've figured it out! Thanks for all the help!